# pandas pivot onto values

Tags: pandas, pivot

Given a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,11,0],[1,12,1],[2,21,0],[2,22,1]])
df.columns = ['Key','Value','PivotOn']
pivoted = df.pivot(index='Key',columns='PivotOn',values='Value')
```

The pivot action will give me columns 0 and 1 from the column 'PivotOn'. But I would like to always pivot onto values 0, 1 and 2, even if there might not exist a row that has PivotOn = 2 (just produce nan for it).

I cannot modify original dataframe so I'd want something like:

```
pivoted = df.pivot(index='Key',columns=[0,1,2],values='Value')
```

where it will always produce 3 columns of 0, 1 and 2 and column 2 is filled with nans.

Comment: what is your expected pivot table looks like including all `0, 1, 2` if say `df` doesn't have `2`?

Comment: Same as the original pivoted dataframe (with column 0 and 1), plus an additional column 2 filled with nans.

Comment: you should accept and upvote meW's answer. be clearer on what you need next time please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `PivotOn` has three unique values `0, 1, 2`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,11,0],[1,12,1],[2,21,0],[2,22,2]])
df.columns = ['Key','Value','PivotOn']
df


+---+-----+-------+---------+
|   | Key | Value | PivotOn |
+---+-----+-------+---------+
| 0 |   1 |    11 |       0 |
| 1 |   1 |    12 |       1 |
| 2 |   2 |    21 |       0 |
| 3 |   2 |    22 |       2 |
+---+-----+-------+---------+
```

And say you need to include columns 2, 3 and 4 (you can also assume that 2 may or may not be present in original `df`, so generalizing)

Then go as -

```
expected = {2, 3, 4}
res = list(expected - set(df.PivotOn.unique()))
if len(res) > 1:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key':np.NaN, 'Value':np.NaN, 'PivotOn':res}, index=range(df.shape[0], df.shape[0] + len(res)))
    ndf = pd.concat([df, new_df], sort=False)
    pivoted = ndf.pivot(index='Key',columns='PivotOn',values='Value').dropna(how='all')
else:
    pivoted = df.pivot(index='Key',columns='PivotOn',values='Value')

pivoted


+---------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
| PivotOn |  0   |  1   |  2   |  3  |  4  |
+---------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
| Key     |      |      |      |     |     |
| 1.0     | 11.0 | 12.0 | NaN  | NaN | NaN |
| 2.0     | 21.0 | NaN  | 22.0 | NaN | NaN |
+---------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this if all you need is a column '2' with nan's when they do not exist in your dataframe;

```
def no_col_2(df):
    if 2 not in df['PivotOn']:
        pivoted = df.pivot(index='Key',columns='PivotOn',values='Value') 
        pivoted['2'] = np.nan
    else:
        pivoted = df.pivot(index='Key',columns='PivotOn',values='Value') 

no_col_2(df) 

print(pivoted)

PivotOn   0   1   2
Key                
1        11  12 NaN
2        21  22 NaN
```

Comment: seems you improvised :D (+1)

Comment: guess that's what he asked...    ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I gave the simplest problem here, but the requirement can be parameterized, say column 0 -10. So is there a more generic and simpler solution?

Comment: that is a different question